# Convert python list to tree structure in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, networkx

I have a list of numbers like `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4]` which I need to convert into a tree, like below:

```
             1
          /  |  \
         2   2   2
            / \  / \
           3   3 3  3
                    \
                     4
```

Note: within the list, each number cannot be +2 or more than +2 compared to the preceding value.

Comment: Hi Ajay, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you include code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a natural way, using a stack of nodes:

- Initialise an empty stack.
- For each number `x` in the list:

  - Create a node `node` with value `x`.
  - Pop until either the stack is empty, or the top node in the stack has value `x - 1`.
  - If the stack is non-empty, add an edge from `node` to the node at the top of the stack.
  - Push `node` to the stack.
- Return the node at the *bottom* of the stack; this is the root node.